# Move all the markers on the map to their updated/new current location periodically as users moves

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm developing an android app where some users opens the same activity from their devices. There is a map in this activity and as users opens this activity from their devices, their location coordinates is fetched from Firebase and a marker based on these coordinates is shown on the map.

Here's my code:

```
acceptingUserReference.child(requestID).child(key).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
            final Map<String, String> newAcceptedUser = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            
            nameOfP.add(newAcceptedUser.get("pName"));                      
            cLatP.add(newAcceptedUser.get("currentLat").trim());
            cLngP.add(newAcceptedUser.get("currentLng").trim());

            addMarkers();

            //Check map is loaded
            mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLoaded() {
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                    mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
                    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
                    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(19.0f);  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                }
            });
            
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's `addMarkers()` method:

```
public void addMarkers() {
    mMap.clear();
    venueMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(venueLat), Double.parseDouble(venueLng)));
    markersList.add(venueMarker);
    for (int i = 0; i < nameOfP.size(); i++) {
        p = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(cLatP.get(i)), Double.valueOf(cLngP.get(i)))).title(nameOfP.get(i).trim()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
        markersList.add(pMarker);
    }
}
```

Here's `onLocationChanged()`:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    currentLtAU = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
    currentLnAU = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
}
```

**The users keeps moving towards a specific location.**

**What I want is** to move the respective markers to the new location as the users moves so that everybody can see where each and everyone currently is. Please help me figure it out.

Comment: What is pMarker? isn't the variable you are assigning you marker to just p? Also, are you getting any errors, or is it just not working?

Comment: I would suggest adding your markers to a `hashmap` based on the users "id" then edit the markers themselves as your app receives the values from Firebase rather than creating new ones every time.

Comment: Call `acceptingUserReference.child(requestID)` whenever `onLocationChanged()` and update your location to `FireBase`

Comment: @KishoreJethava got the part till onLocationChanged(), please describe the part ahead.

Comment: post `onLocationChanged` code.

Comment: @KishoreJethava like what more, bro? whole activity's code?

Comment: `onLocationChanged `

Comment: @KishoreJethava done... please check the edited question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136308/discussion-between-kishore-jethava-and-hammad-nasir).

Answer (score 0):

Save the result of addMarker and later call setPosition on it (result of addMarker).

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if there is nothing wrong with your code. I am sorry I could not find anything wrong with it as it is, but here is a file that you can use as a guideline to find the problem:

http://pastebin.com/9qq484Fz

I hope you solve the problem soon! 
(Apologies for the messy code, it's pretty old)

Comment: thanks for the code, buddy. have you find the other way of doing this as you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39778805/6144372

Comment: and what is `mFriends`?

Comment: @hammadnasir the friendlist and mFriends variables are just lists of friend IDs... Not crucial to the rest of the code.

Comment: `friendList` is being used in `onStart`. From where are you populating it? Please tell me,

Comment: @HammadNasir I'm using friendList to store the Google Play Games Ids of my "friends" I populate it when someone adds a friend. I forgot to remove that from the Pastebin but because it was a guest account I can't change it.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Whenever `onLocationChanged` called means user moved to some distance.

Update user's updated location on `Firebase` in `onLocationChanged` so, other user can find your updated location.

**Note**: use [geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-java) to update user location and see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340949/how-to-save-geofire-coordinates-along-with-other-items-in-firebase-database).

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
mCurrentLocation = location;
currentLtAU = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
currentLnAU = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
}
```

**2.** call `acceptingUserReference.child(requestID)` code when you successfully update user location to `Firebase`

Comment: is it what your are asking?

Comment: was working on another problem... sorry for replying so late...
instead of GeoFIre can I just save keep saving the updated location (whenever the location changes) along with user's other data and then keep calling `acceptingUserReference.child(requestID)` from within `onLocationChanged()`?.

Comment: I'm unable to do this... it's just not happening, bro. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: what not happening?

Comment: whenever I'm trying to fetch updated location in an array, the array gets filled with many items and I gets arrayoutofboundsexception and also many markers are shown on map... something weird is happening. isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: have you checked it out??